# Sails without view engine ?

Tags: sails.js

Is it possible to remove the view engine components from sails js but keep the assets folder ? I would like to serve only static content and have all the communication go through a rest api.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely disable views in your sails open `.sailsrc` and and file should look like this:

```json
{
    "hooks": {
        "views": false
    }
}
```

Comment: `.sailsrc` is included in the `.gitignore` of the sails by default because it is supposed to be local to the machine of developers. in production and on git this file will not be there. you should either include this in your `env/development.js` or `env/production.js` or create your project with `--no-linker`

Answer (score 2):

You can put static files on asstes folder 
Example:
 
You have a html file named : test.html
Put this file on /asstes/ folder 
Now you can access  this file by : 127.0.0.1:1337/test.html

If you put your file to /asstes/somefolder/index.html

You can access by  127.0.0.1:1337/somefolder

Answer (score 2):

create your project with the argument `--no-linker`

like this:

```
sails new --appName myapp --no-linker .
```